# Rsync over SSH getting no tty present

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, rsync, sudo

I'm using the following command in root's crontab on Debian.

```
rsync -vqrlHEAXogDtzhi --log-file=${LOG} --progress --rsync-path="sudo /usr/bin/rsync" --exclude-from=$CONFIG_DIR/excludes -e "ssh -i /home/backups/.ssh/id_rsa" backups@${HOSTNAME}:/ ${BACKUP_DIR}
```

And I'm getting the following:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I have tried adding -t to the ssh command and I get:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

I have tried adding -t -t to the ssh command and I get:

```
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
```

I have added a .hushlogin to the backups user on the remote box and confirmed that I can ssh as backups using a key to the remote box with nothing displayed (login is hushed).  I still get these messages.

Note that I can ssh as backups to the remote box using a key successfully.

Note that my sudo does not have the -tt option.

Note that the following is set in source and destination's /etc/sudoers file:

```
backups ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync
```

Note that my /etc/sudoers file does not have any reference to:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

Note that I won't echo my password in the command.

How can I skin this cat?  :|

Thanks

Comment: hmm... without the `-tt` option, this becomes more difficult.  Maybe upgrade your ssh client if possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes you think too hard about things.

Rsync was not installed on the remote system.

/facepalm

Comment: had this just happen to me, like a fool.

Comment: Yes, check for this first! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Putting this here so I can remember & share this trick:

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -tt" --rsync-path="stty raw -echo; sudo /usr/bin/rsync"   user@${HOSTNAME}:/ ${DEST_DIR}
```

This method seems to bypass the requirement for a tty as [enforced on some system's default `/etc/sudoers` file](https://web.archive.org/web/20200608212236/https://www.shell-tips.com/linux/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo/) with `Defaults requiretty`. This information was crafted after reviewing [this SO question & answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122616/7688).

In that answer, they recommend removing `Defaults requiretty` from `/etc/sudoers`.  This is the easier method.  However, if you are unable to modify the remote host `/etc/sudoers` to remove this configuration option, you can try forcing the local `rsync` to use `ssh -tt`.  This option for `ssh` is described in the [`ssh` client manual page](https://www.mankier.com/1/ssh#-t) like this:

> Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.
>   Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

Thus, we force ssh to allocate a pseudo-tty to avoid the error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Then, the `--rsync-path` is overridden with a command to do the following:

```
stty raw -echo; sudo /usr/bin/rsync
```

`stty raw -echo` is to set the line discipline of the remote terminal as pass through.  This effectively causes it to behave like a pipe that would be used instead of a pseudo-terminal without `-tt`.

Then the remote rsync command will be `sudo /usr/bin/rsync`, which now has a pseudo-tty and will pass the `requiretty` check for `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need `sudo` if the `cron` job is excecuting as root.
2. There's a whole slew of unnecessary flags: `-rlptgoD`; remove and replace with `-a`.
3. The TTY message from `sudo` is for the **local** TTY whereas the `-t` option to `ssh` is for the **remote** TTY. Don't confuse the two.
4. Don't `-v` and `-q` contradict each other?
5. Your last worry should be whether the local SSH private key is encrypted or not. The former cannot be used with unattended runs (e.g., ones where `stdin` is not a TTY; they aren't run from a terminal or terminal emulator).

**EDIT/UPDATE**:

- I take back 1 and 2.
- 3 should be about there being no local TTY when `cron` is running, and SSH doesn't allocate one remotely since there isn't a local one.

Comment: This runs out of roots cronjob but ssh's as backups and over there uses sudo to become root again.

Comment: Right. Misread. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that thus is an ssh key problem. Either backup's private key has a pass phrase or the public key isn't in the remote users keychain. Maybe your previous attempt used a key that was already loaded in your keychain?

Comment: There's no pass phrase and the pubic key is in the remoet user's keychain.